What's wrong with my equations?

I'm trying to get the value of v_o using mesh method as it is required. The equations I'm getting are:
For the mesh on the current A I have:
2 - 2(I_a) - 3(I_a + I_b) - 2(I_a + I_c) = 0
for the mesh on current B I just got:
I_b = 3
and for the mesh on C I have:
2(I_c) + 2(I_c - I_b) - 2(I_c + I_a) = 0.
When I solve I get this equation
I_c - I_a = 3
-7 - 7I_a - 2I_c = 0
When I solve this, I obtain:
I_c = 14/9 and so V_o is 3,11 [V] which is incorrect acording to LTSpice.

For loop C, you have written:
$$ 2I_c + 2(I_c - I_b) - 2(I_c+I_a) = 0 $$
Since \$I_C\$ is flowing upwards through the lower-left 2Ω resistor (please label your components in future), going clockwise around that loop incurs a fall in potential across it, and across all the resistances in that loop.
Remember that the end of a resistor with the higher potential is one where current enters, according to passive sign convention.
So, in keeping with passive sign convention, with respect to \$I_c\$, the correct KVL equation for loop C is:
$$ - 2I_c - 2(I_c - I_b) - 2(I_c+I_a) = 0 $$
or
$$ 2I_c+ 2(I_c - I_b) + 2(I_c+I_a) = 0 $$
depending on the school teaching you. Curiously, you didn't make the same mistake for loop A.

Direct answer pinpointing the error.

Thanks you so much! now i get the mistake that i made. Really appreciate your reply :)

Use currents in clockclockwise or counterclockwise directions. Dont mix both.
Assuming the currents \$I_a\$, \$I_b \$, \$I_c \$ are in clockwise direction. Name the three mesh a,b,c. Use passive sign convention and KVL in each mesh.
Mesh equations:
In mesh a,
$$2(I_a - I_c) + 3(I_a = I_c) + 2I_a +2 = 0$$
In mesh b,
$$ I_b = 3 $$
In mesh c,
$$  2I_c + 2 (I_c - I_b)  + 2(I_c - I_a) = 0 $$
You have two linear equations and two unknowns. Solve using Kramer's rule. The mesh current \$I_b\$ is equal to the current source 3A. Solve for \$I_a\$ and \$I_c\$.
Using passive sign convention, \$V_o = -2I_c \$

It is necessary for the currents to be all in the same direction? Or it is to help in the analysis?

The reason for currents to be in the same direction is to make it easy for the analysis.
